# Role of preempt_disable/enable and raw_local_irq_save/restore in benchmarking

Tags: c++, c, kernel, benchmarking, inline-assembly

The following paper by intel ([link](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf)) describe a method to accurately benchmark code. The core of the benchmark reads as follow (see page 31):

```
preempt_disable();
raw_local_irq_save(flags);

asm volatile ( 
    "CPUID\n\t" 
    "RDTSC\n\t" 
    "mov %%edx, %0\n\t" 
    "mov %%eax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low):: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx"
);

/*call the function to measure here*/ 

asm volatile( 
    "CPUID\n\t" 
    "RDTSC\n\t" 
    "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
    "mov %%eax, %1\n\t": "=r" (cycles_high1), "=r" (cycles_low1):: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx"
); 

raw_local_irq_restore(flags);  
preempt_enable();
```

I was wondering:

- What `raw_local_irq_save` and `raw_local_irq_restore` do?
- What `preempt_disable` and `preempt_enable` do?
- What is their role in that specific context?
- What would be the consequence of removing them from the benchmarking code? Would it prevent correct benchmarking? What could go wrong?

Comment: Those `mov` instructions are not necessary.  Use `=a` and `=d` constraints to tell the compiler which registers the output operands are in.

Comment: If you remove them, your code can be subject to interrupts. However, writing a kernel module just to benchmark some code is also a big undertaking. Another approach is just to do a user-mode benchmark with takes only a short time (less than the typical interrupt frequency), a then take the median or minimum time, essentially avoiding interrupts "statistically". Another approach that I've used is to use the performance counters to check if any interrupts occurred (you can also parse `/proc/interrupts`) and then just redo the test if they did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the link you have provided, if you read section 2.2 where they actually implement the kernel module, you can see there are some comments -

```
preempt_disable(); /*we disable preemption on our CPU*/
```

This is a Linux kernel [function](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.0/ident/preempt_disable) which basically disables the processor to switch context to a different process.

The second call -

```
raw_local_irq_save(flags); /*we disable hard interrupts on our CPU*/  
/*at this stage we exclusively own the CPU*/
```

This masks all the interrupts on the hardware. Again another Linux kernel [function](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.2/ident/raw_local_irq_save).

These two together imply that nothing, even hardware interrupts can disturb the processor till the benchmarking is done. This is to ensure exclusive access to the processors and other resources like cache, TLBs etc. I assume you can figure why that would be necessary for correct benchmarking.

The other two functions, as their names suggest, re-enable preemption and restore the interrupt masks after the benchmarking is done.

As to what will happen, if these calls are removed, well "something" can interrupt your benchmarking process and you can get very high variance in your measurements.